# QT setup for Android

Tags: android, qt, installation

I`m trying to configure Android env for QT but after I chose SDK and NDK and tried to creating the project, QT does not recognize Android Kits.

[image: Picture One]
[image: Picture Two]

Comment: My bet is your versions are too new. See the documentation for the recommended versions.

Comment: @Steve O, did you download qt for Android?

Comment: The problem was that i did not insall Androidx86 for QT version , (QT maintenance tool solved it )