# Cannot setup android kits on QT Creator 8.0.0

Tags: android, qt, qml

I am trying to setup the Android kit for my QT application but I cannot clear these errors:

[image]

I looked at this thread but it is pretty old and did not help much.

[QT setup for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48601767/qt-setup-for-android)

My QT Creator is

Qt Creator 8.0.0
Based on Qt 6.3.1 (MSVC 2019, x86_64)

Anyone knows how I can setup my Android kit on QT Creator 8.0.0

Comment: Did you follow this guide https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/android-getting-started.html ?

Comment: From your screenshot and the following note on the guide posted above my assumption is that your Java version isn't suitable.

**Note: If you are using the SDK Tools 26.x or below, the JDK 8 is required. Versions higher than 8 might cause issues for the Android SDK tools.**